# convert string to char

Tags: iphone, objective-c, char

I have on one string like @"K_h_10_K_d_10_K_c_13_T_c_13_T_s_13"

I separate them by @"_"
using `appCardString=[substringAppCard componentsSeparatedByString:@"_"];`

then I have to convert them in to char and want to put in char[] ....

how can I do that ..

please help me ....

It's crashing here

```
appusedFaces[i]=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[appCardString objectAtIndex:i]] charValue];
```

Comment: `@"\\_"` should not even compile.  You don't need to escape underscore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
appusedFaces[i]=[[appCardString objectAtIndex:i] characterAtIndex:0];
```

Though you should add a check that the string has at least one character. You should also be aware that `char` can only hold character codes up to 255 (`unichar` can handle any Unicode character).

It also looks like you have some numeric codes in your test string. Checking if the string has more than one character and then calling `[[appCardString objectAtIndex:i] intValue]` for those characters will handle these.